# Why am I getting a router error for a static route?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have in my bootstrap

```
public function initRoutes()
{
    $router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('register', array('module'=>'members','controller'=>'register','action'=>'index'));
    $router->addRoute('register',$route);
}
```

and when I go to http://domain.com/register

I get this error:

The following error occurred:

```
exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (register)' in /var/www/html/beta/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:241 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/beta/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(936): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 /var/www/html/beta/application/bootstrap.php(24): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2 /var/www/html/beta/public/index.php(8): require_once('/var/www/html/b...') #3 {main}
```

in the modules/members/controllers directory there is a RegisterController.php with the class Members_RegisterController

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I have referred to the manual on static routes and it seems that this should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are adding a route to a router, but the router is not the one that belongs to your front controller.  The router you created evaporates as soon as your `initRoutes()` function terminates.

You must either use the default router of your front controller:

```
$router = $frontCtrl->getRouter();
$router->addRoute( ... );
```

Or else if you create a new router, set that router to be the router for the front controller:

```
$router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
// ...add routes...
$frontCtrl->setRouter($router);
```